# Convert Date to string showing wrong "2023-07-11 9:07:51\U202fPM" iOS17

Tags: ios, swift, date, format

I am converting the UTC date to a string. when the date convert to string successfully it is showing "2023-07-11 9:07:51\U202fPM".dont know why its added unicode in the string.

```
func toString(formateType type: DateFormate) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC") //TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = type.rawValue
    return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
}
```

Date Format - "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
can you please help me how to fix this

Comment: Are you really sure type.rawValue contains the format you say it does? And could you add a reproducible example?

Comment: add `print(type.rawValue)` at the start of your function,
 and show us **exactly** what it prints,
 when the result of the function is `2023-07-11 9:07:51\U202fPM`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine This issue is happen in only client devices.i have checked in my device and working perfect

Comment: can you show the code for `DateFormate`

Comment: Note, the `\U202f` is the unicode for `Narrow No-Break Space`, a small blank space. Then you have `PM` as 
in `AM` and `PM` meaning afternoon. So I suspect one of your `DateFormate` has this format, and may not render properly. You should show how you display the result of the function `toString(...)`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine calling method like 
tmpDate.toString(formateType: .yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss)

Comment: case yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

Comment: Again, add a reproducible example.

Comment: show the code you use **in context**, not some bits of it you think is happening. Show the code for `DateFormate` and how you use the function `toString` and how you display the results, including any localized string functions.

Comment: Does it work on iOS 16 ?

Answer (score -1):

Check this code

```
func toString(formatTpe: String) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC") //TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = formatTpe
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_us")
        return dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
    }
```

//you need to call like this
let date = toString(formatTpe: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

I have attach screenshot of result
[image]

Comment: How will it help to add a hard coded locale? And why wouldn't the original code work if you passed the correct format string?

Comment: if you don't want to put locale, plz remove it , I guess due to type.rawValue you can't get desired result, check my answer

Comment: Yes your code will work with a correct date format but so will the code posted by OP (which I am not) so this answer doesn't really add anything.